# Django doesn't print array variable in template

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-templates

In my django controller function I get "annotations" of a specific web server from database.

For all annotations I build annotationsId, annotationsCode, annotationsName array.

They are

```
annotationsId = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
annotationsCode = ['codicefiscale', 'partitaiva', 'telefono', 'data', 'targa']
annotationsName = ['codice fiscale', 'partita iva', 'telefono', 'data', 'targa']
```

I pass these arrays to view_process_show_saveandanalize.html through tmplAnnVar.

My output is this

`<li><a class="dropdown-item active" href="#" data-active="1" data-annotation-web-server-id data-annotation-code data-func></a> </li>`

As you can see microdatas (data-annotation-web-server-id example) don't have a value.

```
def show_results(request):
    #verifico che L'utente abbia scelto un server di annotazioni
    isChooseWebServer = False
    userId = int(request.session['id'])
    userWebServerDao = UserWebServerDAO()
    userWebServerRec = userWebServerDao.getUserWebServer(userId)
  
    userWebServerRec = userWebServerRec[0]
    idWebServer = userWebServerRec["web_server_id"]
    
    if idWebServer > 0:
        isChooseWebServer = True

    isThereAnnotation = False
    #ottengo la lista delle annotazioni del server scelto dall'utente
    annotationWebServerDao = AnnotationWebServerDAO()
    annotations = annotationWebServerDao.getAnnotationsWebServer(idWebServer)
    if len(annotations) > 0:
        isThereAnnotation = True

    annotationsName = []
    annotationsCode = []
    annotationsId = []
    i = 0
    for annot in annotations:
        print(annot)
        annotationsId.append(annot["annotation_web_server_id"])
        annotationsCode.append(annot["annotation_code"])
        annotationsName.append(annot["annotation_name"])
        i = i + 1

    print(annotationsCode)
    print(annotationsName)
    print(annotationsId)


    messageSaveAndAnalize = ""
    if isChooseWebServer is False:
        messageSaveAndAnalize = "imposta server annotazioni"
    elif isThereAnnotation is False:
        messageSaveAndAnalize = "Non ci sono annotazioni per il server scelto."
 
    tmplAnnVar = {}
    tmplAnnVar["messageSaveAndAnalize"] = messageSaveAndAnalize
    tmplAnnVar["annotationsId"] = annotationsId
    tmplAnnVar["annotationsCode"] = annotationsCode
    tmplAnnVar["annotationsName"] = annotationsName

    dataAnnotationsRes = ""
 
    dataAnnotationsRes =  render_to_string('pygiustizia/home/view_process_show_saveandanalize.html',{ "tmplAnnVar": tmplAnnVar})
         
    res = {}
    res["status"] = "ok"
    res["data"] = {}
    res["data"]["view_saveandanalize"] = dataAnnotationsRes
    res["redirect"] = ""
    return JsonResponse(res)
```

pygiustizia/home/view_process_show_saveandanalize.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSaveSearch">Salva e analizza</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" 
    data-bs-display="static" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end dropdown-menu-lg-start">
    {% for annotId in tmplAnnVar.annotationsId %} 
        {% with c=forloop.counter0 %}   
        <li><a class="dropdown-item active" 
            href="#" 
            data-active="1" 
            data-annotation-web-server-id = "{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsId.c}}"
            data-annotation-code = "{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsCode.c}}"
            data-func="{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsCode.c}}">{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsName.c}}</a>
        </li>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I test `data-annotation-web-server-id = "{{c}}"` and it print 0,1,2,3,4

I test `data-annotation-web-server-id = "{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsId.0}}"` and it print 1

I test `data-annotation-web-server-id = "{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsId.c}}"` and it print data-annotation-web-server-id namely NOTHING

this is print(res) for brevity only view view_saveandanalize

````
{'status': 'ok', 'data': {'view_saveandanalize': '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSaveSearch">Salva e analizza</button>\n<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" \n    data-bs-display="static" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">\n        <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>\n</button>\n<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end dropdown-menu-lg-start">\n     \n           \n        <li><a class="dropdown-item active" \n            href="#" \n            data-active="1" \n            data-annotation-web-server-id = ""\n            data-annotation-code = ""\n            data-func=""></a>\n        </li>\n    \n     \n           \n        <li><a class="dropdown-item active" \n            href="#" \n            data-active="1" \n            data-annotation-web-server-id = ""\n            data-annotation-code = ""\n            data-func=""></a>\n        </li>\n    \n     \n           \n        <li><a class="dropdown-item active" \n            href="#" \n            data-active="1" \n            data-annotation-web-server-id = ""\n            data-annotation-code = ""\n            data-func=""></a>\n        </li>\n    \n     \n           \n        <li><a class="dropdown-item active" \n            href="#" \n            data-active="1" \n            data-annotation-web-server-id = ""\n            data-annotation-code = ""\n            data-func=""></a>\n        </li>\n    \n     \n           \n        <li><a class="dropdown-item active" \n            href="#" \n            data-active="1" \n            data-annotation-web-server-id = ""\n            data-annotation-code = ""\n            data-func=""></a>\n        </li>\n    \n    \n</ul>'}, 'redirect': ''}```
````

Comment: can you please share `print(res)` - also is this view used async? Why not using common response object but JSON Response?

Comment: Yes, it is used in jquery in async.

Comment: then you would have to update the divs container async as well as Django doesn't render a new html file upon async AJAX request. Go into the response function of your ajax request and update the desired content with the response data.

Comment: Done! My problem is  data-annotation-web-server-id = "{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsId.c}}" isn't rendered. It print  data-annotation-web-server-id ="". I don't understand why?

Comment: because `{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsId.c}}` isn't populated in your JSON/dict. `annotationsId` doesn't have a property `c`

Comment: Also if I use data-annotation-web-server-id = "{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsId.forloop.counter0}}" is the same "" but if I use data-annotation-web-server-id = "{{tmplAnnVar.annotationsId.0}}" it print data-annotation-web-server-id = 1

Comment: c is the index. I use it to access to element like this tmplAnnVar.annotationsId[c]. isn't correct? one moment.